# Have a formula as text in one cell and use that text to put in formula in another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I need to write a "master" program to read from all (around 30) other excel sheets every single month.
[See what I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yuoj.png)

[image]

So basically I have a formula as text in one cell called "joined". What should I write in another cell to treat that "joined" cell as formula, that in that new cell it'll execute code and get a cell D3 from other sheet?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `INDIRECT`, something like `=INDIRECT(B8)` (if I'm interpreting the picture correctly) will get the value in cell D3 in the file and path listed.

But note that these sheets must be open for the function to work. To access "closed" sheets you will need VBA.

Comment: Not true, other functions will take data from closed sheets, however indirect does not.

Comment: I think we misunderstood. Let's say that i formula A1 I have a text cell "SUM(2+3)". It's just text. And then in cell A2 I want to execute code from A1. Simple "=A1" gets my a text but I want to get sum of this equation. Your formula seems do not helping.

Comment: @Petcio oh, whoops, that is not what I got from the question! Maybe this will help https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-factor-12-secret-evaluate-function